# Python-GitLab Unprotect master

Tags: python-gitlab

In the previous version of Python-GitLab after creating the project and adding a user as a developer, we have been using:

```
# Unprotect master
branch = project.branches.get('master')
branch.unprotect()
```

as we wish to allow developer access to the master.

unprotect is no longer available in version 3.2.0 can anyone guide me on how to achieve the same result using the new version

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Protected Branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#protected-branches-api) ([python-gitlab docs](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/protected_branches.html)) for this.

```py
protected_branch = project.protectedbranches.get("master")
protected_branch.delete()

# or simply
project.protectedbranches.delete("master")
```

Note: the `delete()` method in this case simply unprotects it, it does not delete the branch.

To re-protect it, you can then create it again. You can also control access levels directly:

```py
protected_branch = project.protectedbranches.create({
    'name': 'master',
    'merge_access_level': gitlab.const.DEVELOPER_ACCESS,
    'push_access_level': gitlab.const.MAINTAINER_ACCESS
})
```

Comment: This is (most annoyingly) no longer working for me. Randomly, I find that after unprotecting the 'master' branch (using protectedbranches.delete('master'))  that although there are no longer any entries in protectedbranches.list(), the 'master' branch is protected: looping over all branches checking the 'protected' attribute pops up 'master'.  This is confirmed by the web interface. Looking at the list of branches shows 'master' is protected, but the list of protected branches under 'repository' is empty. Still looking for a fix other than protecting/unprotecting.